# How to find the sum of the sequence $\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4} +\frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4} +\frac{3}{1+3^2+3^4}+.....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Problem :

How to find the sum of the sequence $\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4} +\frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4} +\frac{3}{1+3^2+3^4}+.....$

I am unable to find out how to proceed in this problem.. this is a problem of arithmetic progression... Please suggest how to proceed...Thanks..

Comment: I just did this question today, seemed rather familiar when I saw it, I would be interested to know the source where you got this problem :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HINT:

As $1+r^2+r^4=(1+r^2)^2-(r)^2=(1+r+r^2)(1-r+r^2)$

and $(1+r+r^2)-(1-r+r^2)=2r,$

$$\frac r{1+r^2+r^4}$$

$$=\frac12\cdot\frac{2r}{(1+r+r^2)(1-r+r^2)}$$

$$=\frac12\cdot\frac{(1+r+r^2)-(1-r+r^2)}{(1+r+r^2)(1-r+r^2)}$$

$$=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-r+r^2}-\frac1{1+r+r^2}\right)$$

Put the values of $r=1,2,\cdots.. n-1,n$ to find the [partial sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialSum.html)
 and recognize the [Telescoping Sum/Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) which is evident as $1-(r+1)+(r+1)^2=1+r+r^2$

Then set $n\to\infty$