# Computing partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to compute the partial sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{n}{n^4+n^2+1}$. Wolfram Alpha says that the answer is $\displaystyle\frac{m^2+m}{2(m^2+m+1)}$. I have no idea how they got this answer. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hint: $n^4+n^2+1=(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n+1)$. Break it up into partial fractions.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449510/how-to-find-the-sum-of-the-sequence-frac111214-frac212224

Comment: Hmm...duplicate question...sorry. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac n{n^4+n^2+1}=\frac n{(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)}=\frac 12(\frac 1{n^2-n+1}-\frac 1{n^2+n+1})$ Does it telescope?