# Find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n}{n^4+2n^2+9}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{4n}{n^4+2n^2+9}.$$

By calculator, we can predict that its sum is equal to $\dfrac{5}{6}$ so I think we should use inequalities to prove it. And I found that

$\dfrac{5}{6(n^4+n^2)} < \dfrac{4n}{n^4+2n^2+9}< \dfrac{5}{6(n^2+n)}$ for all $n\ge n_0$, $n_0$ is large enough.

And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{5}{6(n^4+n^2)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{5}{6(n^2+n)}=\dfrac{5}{6}$.

But it is not enough to confirm that the given series converges to $\dfrac{5}{6}$. Can someone help me, please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How can $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{5}{6(n^4+n^2)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{5}{6(n^2+n)}$ be correct??? The former is strictly smaller than the latter.

Comment: These two series both converges to $\dfrac{5}{6}$ thus I wrote so. Isn't it   right? Thank you for caring about my problem.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449510/how-to-find-the-sum-of-the-sequence-frac111214-frac212224  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304851/evaluate-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack2-1k4k21

Comment: @liverpool29: It is *not* true that $\sum _{n \ge 1} \frac 5 {6(n^4 + n^2)} = \frac 5 6$.

Comment: @liverpool29, the second series indeed converges to $5/6$.  But the first series converges to something *less* than $5/6$, because, as guestDiego pointed out, each term in the first series (beyond $n=1$) is *less* than the corresponding term in the second series.

Comment: It is known that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n^2+n)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)=1$. However  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(n^4+n^2)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}-\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\right)<1$

Comment: Thank you all again. I understand now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$$(n^2)^2+3^2+2n^2=(n^2+3)^2-(2n)^2=(n^2+2n+3)(n^2-2n+3)$$

$$(n^2+2n+3)-(n^2-2n+3)=?$$

Now if $f(m)=m^2-2m+3,$

$f(m+2)=(m+2)^2-2(m+2)+3=m^2+2m+3$

Comment: How do you math so fast!?

Comment: So is this a type of telescoping series?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, Right you are.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{4n \over n^{4} + 2n^{2} + 9}}$.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{4n \over n^{4} + 2n^{2} + 9}  =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{4n \over \pars{n^{2} - 2n + 3}\pars{n^{2} + 2n + 3}}
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{2} - 2n + 3} - {1 \over n^{2} + 2n + 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{n - 1}^{2} + 2} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{N}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{2} + 2}} =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{n = -1}^{N - 1}{1 \over n^{2} + 2} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{N + 1}{1 \over n^{2} + 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over 3} + {1 \over 2} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}{1 \over n^{2} + 2} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1}{1 \over n^{2} + 2} - {1 \over N^{2} + 2} -
{1 \over \pars{N + 1}^{2} + 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{{5 \over 6} - {1 \over N^{2} + 2} -
{1 \over \pars{N + 1}^{2} + 2}} = \bbx{\ds{5 \over 6}}
\end{align}

---